# How to make conditionally required class property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create an Event class with a data property which is typed based on the type of the event. Here's the code:

```
export interface EventTypes {
  localeChange: {
    locale: string;
  };
  translationsChange: undefined;
}

export default class Event<T extends keyof EventTypes> {
  eventType: T;

  data: EventTypes[T];

  constructor(
    eventType: T,
    ...data: EventTypes[T] extends undefined ? [] : [EventTypes[T]]
  ) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
    this.data = data[0];
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve:

- if the event type does not accept any data (e.g.
  "translationsChange"), the constructor should have just one argument
  and the data property of the instance should be undefined.
- if the
  event type requires additional data (e.g. "localeChange"), the
  constructor should have 2 arguments and the data property of the
  instance should have the corresponding type (as defined in
  `EventTypes`).

The code above basically works, but I'm getting a ts error on the following line:

```
this.data = data[0];

Type 'EventTypes[T] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'EventTypes[T]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'EventTypes[T]'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

If I change the definition of the property to `data?: EventTypes[T];` the error goes away, but the property is then always potentially undefined - even at instances with event type that requires data.

I would really appreciate an advice on how should I type the `data` property to make it compatible with the constructor and typed exactly as defined in the `EventTypes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make data optional as you cannot assign undefined variable to the required one and vice versa.

```
  export default class Event<T extends keyof EventTypes> {
  eventType: T;

  data?: EventTypes[T]; //Making data optional

  constructor(
    eventType: T,
    ...data: EventTypes[T] extends undefined ? [] : [EventTypes[T]]
  ) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
    this.data = data[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, that's what I feared. Thank you!